# How to redirect time command output under Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, time, redirect

There are several posts discussing the redirection of time command output to a file. For example

```
(time my_program) 2> out

{ time my_program ; } 2> out
```

They worked under Linux but they did not work under my Mac OS X machine with Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0.

```
(time my_program) 2> out
Badly placed ()'s.

{ time my_program ; } 2> out
{: Command not found.
}: Command not found.

time --version
--version: Command not found.
0.000u 0.000s 0:00.00 0.0%      0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w

/usr/bin/time --version
/usr/bin/time: illegal option -- -
usage: time [-lp] command.
```

Under my Mac machine, there are shell-built-in `time` and `/usr/bin/time`. Neither of them provides the -o option. Because my program runs for a few days, and I want to time it, how can I redirect the output of `time` to a file under Mac OS X?

Comment: In what way don't they work? Do you have permissions to create the `out` file in the current working directory? Is the `out` file created? Is it empty or does it contain data? Have you tested with small programs such as `ls(1)` as well as your program?

Comment: Try `time my_program >& out`?

Comment: what version is /usr/bin/time ?

Comment: Both work for me under OS X 10.7.3.  But if you have OS X 11.2.0, you are clearly traveling backward in time, and your `time` command probably errors out trying to display a negative "real" time.

Comment: Mac OS X is the latest Lion with Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0.

Comment: Sometimes the out file was created, sometimes not. When out was created, sometimes it was empty, sometimes it was the output of my_program. It never contained the output of time.

Comment: I tried "time my_program >& out". out was created, with the output of my_program as its content. The output of time was directly output to stdout.

Comment: I was not able to find the version of /usr/bin/time. I tried /usr/bin/time --version, but it said it was an illegal option.

Comment: I just found a solution. Download the GNU time v1.7 and compile it from C source under Mac OS X. Now there is the -o option. Redirection no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is really late, but the following command worked for me.

```
{ time ls > command.output 2>&1 ; } 2> time.out
```